# A book that contains a proof on the infinity case of L' Hospitals Rule

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I own three calculus books and all of them prove the $\displaystyle\frac{0}{0}$ case but none even give a rough idea for the $\displaystyle\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ case. Any books I can see pdf's of that do prove it? I would prefer to see a proof that does not use the epsilon delta proof for now. Don't get me wrong, I do not hate epsilon delta proofs. I just want to see the proof without it for now. Thanks!

Comment: If my memory serves me well Tom Apostol's calculus book contains a geometric proof of the $\infty/\infty $ case.

Comment: The best reference in this case is the proof given in wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ case is not very different and if you have proved the $\frac{0}{0}$ case you can use that to prove the former one.

Consider
$$\lim_{x\to h}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$
where $\lim_{x\to h}f(x)=\lim_{x\to h}g(x)=\infty$

Let $f_2(x)=\frac{1}{f(x)}$ and $g_2(x)=\frac{1}{g(x)}$ so $\lim_{x\to h}f_2(x)=\lim_{x\to h}g_2(x)=0$ and:

$$\lim_{x\to h}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to h}\frac{g_2(x)}{f_2(x)}$$

You can then use the $\frac{0}{0}$ prove to then prove this.

Comment: And how would the proof go if you get an infinity over infinity situation for $x$ going to infinity?

Comment: @imranfat: put $x = 1/y$ and let $y$ tend to $0$.

Comment: ok thanks. makes sense

Comment: We have $f/g$ in the $\infty/\infty$ case. We want $f'/g'\to L \implies f/g \to L.$ The suggestion is to look at $(1/g)/(1/f),$ which puts us in the $0/0$ case. So if we can show $(1/g)'/(1/f)' \to L,$ we'll be done. How does $f'/g'\to L \implies (1/g)'/(1/f)' \to L?$

Comment: This answer shows intuitively why LHR applies in the $\infty/\infty$ case, but it is not a valid proof, petitio principii.  As hinted by @zhw $(1/g)'/(1/f)' = (f/g)^2(f'/g')^{-1}$.  Given only that $f'/g' \to L$ we cannot conclude that $(1/g)'/(1/f)' \to L$ because that assumes $f/g$ converges - which is what must be proved.